# How to access an object literal property from another property?

Tags: javascript, json, object, element

This is probably incredibly simple and my Google-fu is just not strong enough. My apologies if it is a duplicate.

Consider the following object literal:

```
var config = {
    url: 'http://google.com',
    message: 'You must go to <a href="' + url + '">Google</a> to search!'
};
```

I get an error saying that `url is not defined`. How do I access the url element from the message element?

Comment: Long story short, you won't be able to within the declaration. You can leave out `message`, and then add it in after declaring `config`, referencing `config.url`

Comment: Hmmm, what does _url is undefined_ mean?

Comment: @SalmanA, I should have said 'url is not defined'. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can wrap the `config` object, e.g.

```
var config = (function() {
  var _url = 'http://google.com';
  return {
    url : _url,
    message : 'You must go to <a href="' + _url + '">Google</a> to search!'
  }
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

You may just do this

```
var config = {
    url: 'http://google.com',
    message: function () { return 'You must go to <a href="' + this.url + '">Google</a> to search!' }
};
```

And call

```
config.message();
```

to get the message.